# Java Melody Memory Histogram not working for Multiple web apps

Tags: java, tomcat6, monitoring, histogram, java-melody

Am using Tomcat 6.0.37, on which have deployed applications(consider 2 now) for which added code for java melody in their web.xml respectively.

When i try to get memory histogram for any web application it works fine, but when i try for next application it gives me a error.(Other monitoring works fine, only memory histogram not working)

Error am getting :
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\attach.dll already loaded in another classloader

Guys any suggestions how to resolve this.

Using java_melody_1.48
and jrobin-1.59
tomcat6.0.37